# Architecture Missmatch

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

I'm trying to run a java program that links to an Access database in netbeans. I am aware that Access is 32bit and the JDK is 64bit. I created the link using `%WINDIR%\SYSWOW64\ODBCAD32.exe`.

Now, I'm getting this error: `Architecture mismatch`. What do I have to install to be able to run this program? I have tried to find a solution on here, but I just don't understand the exact steps I need to follow.

Comment: I know this is a common problem. Nobody has any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You will need 64-bit drivers as your Java app is running 64-bit. I believe there is a 64-bit download at the below link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: If you are running 64bit windows the 64bit odbc admin is located in the \windows\sytem32 folder (still named odbcad32.exe -- the 32bit version is in syswow64  - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976